# Verilog counter is not working using @always statement

Tags: fpga, verilog, hdl

I am trying to implement counter using Verilog HDL

```
output reg testLED;
reg [30:0] counter;
reg [30:0] sec = 0;
always @ (posedge clock50MHz)
begin
     if(sec>10) testLED = 1;
     counter<= counter+1;
     if (counter == 30'd50_000_000) begin
        counter<=0;
        sec = sec +1;
     end
end
```

However, this code is not working properly. testLED lights up immediately after startup.
Moreover, when I tried to do it using assign, the counter worked properly.

```
output testLED;
reg [30:0] counter;
reg [30:0] sec = 0;

always @ (posedge clock50MHz)
begin
    counter <= counter+1;
    if (counter == 30'd50_000_000) begin
    counter<=0;
        sec = sec +1;
    end
end

assign testLED = (sec>10) ? 1 :0;
```

What is the reason of this behaviour and how make the counter work without "assign"?

Comment: When you run a simulation, what is the initial value of `counter`?

Comment: I haven't tested in simulator. I am using DE10-Lite FPGA board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initialized 'counter', but that's not the only issue.

The two statements don't do the same thing. If you replace

```
 if(sec>10) testLED = 1;
```

With

```
testLED <= (sec>10) ? 1:0;
```

(and deal with initializing 'counter') then it should work. Note the use of a non-blocking assignment <=  in the sequential block, also note that a value is assigned on every single clock edge. If you don't assign a value on every edge, a flip-flop is needed to retain the previous value (in this case, an uninitialized value).

You could alternatively add a combinational block using a a blocking assignment:

```
always @ (*)
begin 
   if(sec>10) testLED = 1;
      else testLED = 0; 
end
```

or even

```
always @ (*)
begin 
   testLED = 0; 
   if(sec>10) testLED = 1;
end
```

They are equivalent give or take one 50MHz clock edge.